# make a printer page counter vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing

I have been asked to monitor the amount and type of prints within our department. Our department uses 3 printers (two the same model 1 different)

Is it possible to keep track of the type of print (paper size A4, A3, ect) and the amount of prints made using VB.net, regardless of what application was used to make the print (Notepad, word, paint, ect...

Comment: Check [`this link`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3313/Monitoring-a-Printer-Queue-from-VB-NET)

Comment: Most printer drivers pass the "number of copies" to the printer so that the printer itself stores the document once and repeats it as needed.  Takes the burden off the spooler.  That however spells doom to your project since you cannot see this in the print queue properties.  The PrintQueue class is in general very hard to deal with, it doesn't have any events.  Printer manufacturers tend to have "management" software to provide the equivalent functionality.